# Is there a sub-topic of graph theory that "attaches" a function to each node/edge?

Tags: graph-theory, mathematical-modeling, advice, research

I'm going through Graph Theory by Bondy, U. S. R. Murty and trying to get a grasp of basic graph theory, and am looking for literature (if it exists) that deals with graphs in which there is a " function attached to each node/edge" of sort. An example would be a situation (or if you could call it a game) where we start from a node, and where you can move between nodes in the fashion as in directed graphs, but in addition to that, moving once increases a time counter, and the said function is a function of that counter. The nodes or the edges could change in weight, as well as the direction of the edge, or a node could become inaccessible altogether depending on the input of the function.

More specifically, I'm looking to model a situation where we apply the said function to a (possibly) unique ordered set attached with each node/edge, and where the function at, say $T=n$, gives $n^{th}$ element in the set.

I know what I'm asking for could be way too specific, but any help or even a nudge in right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: What you're asking for is not too specific but rather too general. "A function attached to each node/edge" is a very common situation that can arise for many unrelated reasons, and so there's no unifying sub-field of graph theory that deals with all of them at once. If you elaborate more on what you're trying to do, you can get a more precise answer.

Comment: You may be interested in combinatorial game theory, and sequential games. A chip-firing game (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chip-firing_game) is a game on (undirected) graphs that sort-of sounds like what you are interested in, at least at first glance.